# importing table with phpmyadmin takes too long time

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

i've imported a mysql table stored in a .sql file using my localhost phpymadmin, the table has 14000 records (simple data, 5 fields only) and it took almost 10 minutes. is this normal? i'm running a laptop with win8, core i7 quad and my xampp seems to be configured properly.
thanks

Comment: Bulk inserts or single inserts per row? Using mysql directly will be a lot faster anyhow.

Comment: single inserts per row

Answer (score -2):

Your hard drive is the limit in this case. Having a single insert per row means your inserting is limited on your hard drives IOPS (I/O operations per second).

Bulk inserting reduces the IOPS but increases the MB/s transfer which is what you want in this case.

so rewriting like

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,4)
```

with comma separated rows will give a huge boost

Putting in a hard drive with higher IOPS will speed it up also if the rewritten query is still slow